# Codeigniter 2.1 - Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am a bit new to the routing with CI, and I don't understand it quite well (to be honest not at all). I have following url which need to be changed:

> domain.com/mali_oglasi/index/1(some number)

It is used for pagination, and I need it to be shorten to:

> domain.com/mali_oglasi

I tried:

> $route['mali_oglasi/index/(:num)'] = 'mali_oglasi';

but it doesn't seems to work(nothing is changed). What am I doing wrong, what needs to be changed?

Index function from the controller **mali_oglasi**:

```
function index() {     

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'mali_oglasi/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('ad');
    $config['per_page'] = 10;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();


    $data['title'] = "Mali Oglasi | 010";
    $data['oglasi'] =  $this->mgl->mgl_get_all_home($config['per_page']);
    $data['loc'] = $this->gi_loc;
    $data['cat'] = $this->gi_cat;
    $data['stylesheet'] = $this->css;
    $data['main_content'] = 'mali_oglasi';

    $this->load->view('template',$data);
}
```

Comment: Physically shorten? As in shorten it in the URL bar?

Comment: That is the idea. I want to loose incex/1 part of the url.

Comment: i think that should be fine...can you post your index part from your controller?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .htaccess for what you are trying to achieve, more importantly, the "mod_rewrite" part:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=htaccess+rewrite

CodeIgniter routing doesn't change the look of the URL, it simply changes it's destination.

Comment: @Sasha There's quite a few good tutorials out there, don't worry :-)

Answer (score 0):

Codeignitor routing is simple as

```
    serverpath(base_url)/controller/method(function)/para1/valu1/para2/valu2...
```

you hide index file from defining .htaccess rule(creating file).

more info please visit : [user_guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) in Easily you are understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$route['mali_oglasi/(:num)'] = 'mali_oglasi/index/$1';
```

Your **domain.com/mali_oglasi/index/1** can then be accessed at **domain.com/mali_oglasi/1**

**Edit:**
To loose the /1 just do:

```
 $route['mali_oglasi'] = 'mali_oglasi/index/1';
```

Comment: `$route['mali_oglasi'] = 'mali_oglasi/index/1';` this will always return 1 to index function .. that is not right

Comment: You should probably rethink the code then, but overall if you are new to codeigntier rewriting code architecture error with htaccess is not a good road to follow.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$route['mali_oglasi/(:num)'] = 'mali_oglasi/index/$1';
```

it will help you 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

and for pagination you can add this

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

its optional but better to add